# what happens if high wave length em wave interact with low wave length em wave

Tags: electromagnetism

normal visible light undergoes interference and diffraction with medium,object and slits,what happens when a visible light strikes or goes through a field of 
a) high frequency electromagnetic waves
b)low frequency electromagnetic waves

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer but...

Light, EM wave do not interact with each other in the traditional sense of interaction in particle physics.  There is no EM-EM coupling term like with QCD.  However light in the classical sense is a vector field and if you had to different fields moving through space they would add like vectors at every point and at every instant of time.

For example if you had 2 plane waves with the same polarization direction (let's say Z) traveling in different directions in the x-y plane then at every point you have,

E = E0*(sin(dot(k1,r) - w1*t) + sin(dot(k2,r) - w2*t + phi))

Where k1 and k2 are wave vectors, r is position vector, w1, and w2 are the different frequencies.  You can put this in MATLAB and plot |E| for several cases and see what you get.

Comment: It happens all the time.  The space around you is filled with radio waves, TV waves, cell phone waves, and light.

Comment: @R.W.Bird, yes, I agree.